# Keys: Reorganizing definition list based on attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I posted a question about keys yesterday, and got very helpful responses. I've been working on the last detail in this particular file set most of today; there must just be something I'm missing when it comes to the proper use of keys.

I have the following definition list:

```
<dl>
<dlentry>
<dt>BLARG a</dt>
<dd>BLARG Definition b</dd>
</dlentry>
<dlentry>
<dt outputclass="values">Value c<ph> Value Description d</ph></dt>
<dd/>
</dlentry>
<dlentry>
<dt outputclass="values">Value e<ph> Value Description f</ph></dt>
<dd/>
</dlentry>
<dlentry>
<dt outputclass="values">Value g<ph> Value Description h</ph></dt>
<dd/>
</dlentry>
<dlentry>
<dt>BLARG2 i</dt>
<dd>BLARG2 Description j</dd>
</dlentry>
<dlentry>
<dt outputclass="values">Value k
<ph>Value description l</ph></dt>
<dd/>
</dlentry>
<dlentry>
<dt outputclass="values">Value m
    <ph>Value description n</ph></dt>
<dd/>
</dlentry>
<dlentry>
    <dt outputclass="values">Value o
    <ph>Value description p</ph></dt>
<dd/>
</dlentry>
<dlentry><dt>BLARG3 q</dt>
<dd>BLARG3 Definition r</dd></dlentry>
</dl>
```

Here is my transformation (that doesn't quite work -- I had it closer than this earlier today, but managed to make it worse):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="dlentry[child::dt/@outputclass='values']" 
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::dlentry[not(child::dt/@outputclass='values')])"/>

<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dd[../following-sibling::dlentry[1]/dt[@outputclass='values']]">
    <xsl:variable name="vFollowing" select="key('kFollowing',generate-id(..))"/>
    <dd><xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <table>
            <tgroup cols="2">
                <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" colwidth="*"/>
                <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2" colwidth="*"/>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:for-each select="../following-sibling::dlentry[key('kFollowing',$vFollowing)]">
                        <row>
                            <entry colname="1">
                                <xsl:value-of select="./dt/text()"/>
                            </entry>
                            <entry colname="2">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="./dt/ph/text()"></xsl:apply-templates>
                            </entry>
                        </row>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tbody>
            </tgroup>
        </table></dd>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my desired output:

```
<dl>
<dlentry>
    <dt>BLARG a</dt>
    <dd>BLARG Definition b
    <table>
        <tgroup cols="2">
            <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" colwidth="*"/>
            <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2" colwidth="*"/>
            <tbody>
                <row>
                    <entry colname="1">Value c</entry>
                    <entry colname="2">Value Description d</entry>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <entry colname="1">Value e</entry>
                    <entry colname="2">Value Description f</entry>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <entry colname="1">Value g</entry>
                    <entry colname="2">Value Description h</entry>
                </row>
            </tbody>
        </tgroup>
    </table></dd>
</dlentry>
<dlentry>
    <dt>BLARG2 i</dt>
    <dd>BLARG2 Definition j
        <table>
            <tgroup cols="2">
                <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" colwidth="*"/>
                <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2" colwidth="*"/>
                <tbody>
                    <row>
                        <entry colname="1">Value k</entry>
                        <entry colname="2">Value Description l</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry colname="1">Value m</entry>
                        <entry colname="2">Value Description n</entry>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <entry colname="1">Value o</entry>
                        <entry colname="2">Value Description p</entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </tgroup>
        </table></dd>
</dlentry>
<dlentry><dt>BLARG3 q</dt>
    <dd>BLARG3 Definition r<dd></dlentry>
</dl>
```

**Grouping rules** (Sean's edit)

nodes are grouped on  nodes which do NOT have a dt[outputclass="values"] child, AND all following sibling  nodes which DO have a dt[outputclass="values"] child.

The transformation of  nodes are thus grouped. Note that if the group has only one member in it (that is to say no dlentry s with a dt[outputclass="values"], then the table output as shown in the sample output document is to be suppressed.

Comment: Chad: What are the rules for the transformation? I cannot see where grouping is required and what constitutes a group.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Going by his trial stylesheet, I think the grouping is this: Each dlentry node that does NOT have a dt child with @outputclass='values', is the head of a group. And members of the group all all the following dlEntry nodes until the next header-type dlEntry node is found. The repeated use of the word 'Value' in the sample input document makes it a bit hard to work out his rules of transformation, but clues are given in the trial style-sheet. I think his style-sheet is more-or-less right - Its just that his for-each is broken.

Comment: I'll edit his input and output documents to make it a bit clearer. It may take a while for the edits to get approved.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that could have been a lot clearer. The intent is this: I want to copy all `dlentry` nodes as-is, but any series of `dlentry` nodes that all contain a `dt[@outputclass='values']` should be grouped under the preceding-sibling `dlentry`'s `dd` as a two-column table. I'm glad Sean was able to guess that from my almost certainly humorous attempt at a transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="dl-group" match="dlentry[child::dt/@outputclass='values']" 
    use="generate-id( preceding-sibling::dlentry[ not( child::dt/@outputclass='values')][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dlentry/dd">
 <xsl:variable name="head" select="generate-id(..)" />      
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <xsl:if test="count( key('dl-group',$head))"> 
   <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
   <table>
    <tgroup cols="2">
     <colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" colwidth="*"/>
     <colspec colnum="2" colname="col2" colwidth="*"/>
     <tbody>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('dl-group',$head)" >
       <row>
        <entry colname="1">
         <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(./dt/text())" />
        </entry>
        <entry colname="2"><xsl:value-of select="./dt/ph/text()" /></entry>
       </row>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </tbody>
    </tgroup>
   </table>
  </xsl:if> 
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dlentry[dt[@outputclass='values']]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**

This is just a straight forward application of keys. It looks like you were over-complicating things. Perhaps you were thinking of muenchian grouping. We put the id of the header dd node in a variable to save re-computation. To produce the rows, we simply iterate over the node set returned by the key() function.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Sean. This looks promising. I'll give it a try in the morning and provide more detailed feedback. I will note that I had to Google muenchian grouping, so I was probably not thinking of it.

Comment: This solution does exactly what I needed, without any modification. I really was overengineering things. Thank you very much for your help!